# How to sort Observable<string> type column in angular mat-table?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material-table

Is it possible to sort Observable type column in Angular mat-table?

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: Observable<string>;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
```

I want to sort column "**name**".

please find stackblitz example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-sort-obs?file=src/app/table-sorting-example.ts

Comment: I've answered your question, but please post the relevant code directly in your question. It should not rely on an exterior link that may break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It can't sort the `name` column because the values are observables. You need to make the entire array an observable instead.

```js
const data$: Observable<PeriodicElement[]> = of([
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  ...
]);
```

```js
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>();

  ngOnInit() {
    data$.subscribe((data) => (this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)));
  }
```

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-sort-obs-vcifxy?file=src/app/table-sorting-example.ts

If it's not possible to modify the original array, you'll have to create a second array and subscribe to each name individually, updating the new array on change.